# PHP INTO не работает данные не вносятся в таблицу кавычки и апостроф не помогли

Tags: php, mysql

Форма отправки данных:

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_lesson.php">

<label>Ввеcти название страницы <br>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти краткое описание страницы<br>
<input type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d">
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти ключевые слова для страницы<br>
<input type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k">
</label>
</p> 
<p>
<label>Ввеcти Дату<br>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date">
</label>
</p>
</p> 
<p><label>Ввеcти  описание страницы с тегами<br>
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</label></p> 
<p><label>Ввеcти полный текст страницы с тегами<br>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</label></p>
<p>
<label>Ввеcти Автора урока<br>
<input type="text" name="autor" id="autor">
</label>
</p> 
<p> <label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Занести данные страницы в базу">
</label>
</p>
</form>
```

Сам обработчик:

```php
<?php 

include ("blocks/bd.php");

if ($title == ' ') {unset($title);}
if ($meta_d == ' ') {unset($meta_d);}
if ($meta_k == ' ') {unset($meta_k);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($date);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($description);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($text);}
if ($text == ' ') {unset($autor);}
?>


<?php 

if (isset ($title) && isset ($meta_d) && isset ($meta_k) && isset ($date) && isset ($description) && isset ($text) && isset ($autor))
{
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO new (title,meta_d,meta_k,date,description,text,autor) VALUES (`$title`,`$meta_d`,`$meta_k`,`$date`,'$description`,`$text`,`$autor`)"); 
if ($result == 'true') {echo "<p>Ваша страница успешно добавлена!</p>";}
else {echo "<p>Ваша страница не добавлена!</p>";}
}
else 
{
echo "<p>Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому страница в базу не может быть добавлена.</p>";
}
?>
```

При попытке отправки получаю сообщение:

> Вы ввели не всю информацию, поэтому страница в базу не может быть добавлена.

Как это исправить?

---

```html
<P>ФОРМА ОТПРАВКИ В БД МЕТОД POST</P>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_lesson.php">

  <label>Ввеcти название страницы
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
  </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти краткое описание страницы
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="meta_d" id="meta_d">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти ключевые слова для страницы
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="meta_k" id="meta_k">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти Дату
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
    </label>
  </p>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти описание страницы с тегами
      <br>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти полный текст страницы с тегами
      <br>
      <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Ввеcти Автора урока
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Занести данные страницы в базу">
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

`$title = $_POST['title'];`
тоесть это нужно в эту форму добавить ?
А куда именно ?

Comment: '$description` - разные кавычки, вопервых, во вторых поля нужно получать из массива $_POST['name']

Comment: у вас тут беда со вложенностью тегов, </p></p>два раза закрывается подряд после "Ввеcти Дату"

Comment: Может я олдфаг и у сейчас принято кодить как макака задницей, но я всё же считаю что надо изучить основы языка, чтобы не было таких в корне дурных вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

и так далее для всех полей из формы